# Индивидуальные свойства базового класса

Tags: php, классы

Нужно объявить **свойство** базового класса так, чтобы оно не наследовалось потомками (производными от него)?

P.S. Как **final** для **методов**.

**UPD**

private не подойдёт - массив должен быть доступным, смысл - в экономии, может, на "копейках", но всё же... У базового класса массив данных, а подклассы используются часто и таскают за собой ненужный груз.

Единственное, что приходит на ум, переопределить свойство в каждом подклассе на пустое, но хотелось бы красиво. ))

**UPD2**

Пока сделал так:

```
//базовый класс
class BClass{
    public $cur_array = array('данные');
    ...
}
//решение проблемы
class CLEAR extends BClass{
    public $cur_array = array();
}
//теперь подклассы наследую уже от CLEAR 
class SUBClass extends CLEAR{
    ....    
}
```

Comment: Не наследовалось? Может, private подойдет? Или вам его использовать потом надо? Ну так тогда можно через метод, который final. ))

Comment: Вопрос обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, тогда `static private $param`? Массив создан будет, но будет в одном экземпляре, поэтому на это можно будет внимания не обращать.

А может, лучше пересмотреть схему наследования? Если вы используете функциональность, которая вам нафиг не нужна в дочерних классах, то зачем вы наследуетесь от этого класса?

Может быть, стоит выделить класс, который действительно является базовым, а от него унаследовать ваш "текущий базовый" и все его потомки. Тогда в измененном "текущем базовом" можно будет хоть что делать.

**Обновление**

`static` - это временное решение, следующим шагом должно быть создание класса `BClassAdditional`, который наследуется от `BClass`. Везде, где вам нужен ваш массив - вы используете именно этот класс. Ну и потихоньку переносить функционал, связанный с `cur_array` в этот новый класс (если, конечно, `cur_array` должен только в нем использоваться).

Comment: Я уже думал, чтобы этот массив убрать отдельно! Наследуюсь, потому что только через время понадобился этот массив, его удобно было вписать именно в баз. класс... сейчас вот накидал временное решение, обновлю вопрос.

Comment: > private не подойдёт - оно также унаследуется

Что?

Пожалейте людей, прекратите говнокодить.

Comment: BOPOH'у спасибо за static, скорее всего, это и есть решение проблемы...

Comment: Обновил ответ.